# Logging a user out with Firebase 3 and Swift still shows the `currentUser`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log a user out with Firebase 3 in my iOS application. Here is my code:

```
do {

        databaseReference.child("Users").child(CUUID!).removeAllObservers()

        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

        print("FIRUSER - \(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser)")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logOutSegue", sender: self)

    } catch let logOutError {

        print("Error Logging User Out - \(logOutError)")
    }
```

What I am trying to do is perform a segue back to the login screen if a user is successfully logged out. In order to check if a user was logged out, I print `currentUser` to see if there is still one. I hit the `logOut` button and the segue works (no catch -> no error), but when the `print("FIRUSER - \(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser)")` code runs, I still get a currentUser. **Why is the user not being logged out?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `cmd+click` on the **signOut()** of `try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()` and you will be directed to its documentation , There you will see

---

> - @param listener The block to be invoked. **The block is always invoked asynchronously on the main
>             thread**, even for it's initial invocation after having been added as a listener.
> - @remarks The block is invoked immediately after adding it according to it's standard invocation
>             semantics, **asynchronously on the main thread**.

---

**Asynchronously** which means that your query for signing out the user is loaded in a separate thread in the network link, Which takes time (maybe only milliseconds, but still..) and your `print` line executes even before it has logged user out.Thats the reason why you still receive the *currentUser* from firebase...:)

Try printing the **currentUser** in the *viewWillAppear(animated:Bool)* of the class where you migrate to after performing segue, if it signs out w/o catching any error's, print line must show you nil.

PS:- **Hypothetically** speaking if the *signOut()* function had a completionBlock: , and you tried printing the *currentUser* there , you probably would had found nil, and probably crashed your app...Again this is just hypothetical

BTW :- Best way to get the current user is by setting a listener on the Auth object

```
  FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
          if let user = user {
              // User is signed in.
           } else {
             // No user is signed in.
          }
    }
```

Firebase Docs :- [Get Current User - Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Sorry I forgot to upvote and accept!