# Swift 4 & Firebase: onDisconnectRemoveValue fired when app go background

Tags: swift, firebase, swift4

One of my company's app's requirements is a tracking system, where a user can track other nearby users when using our app. So there is a map and user's location (coordinates) will be updating to Firebase so other users can see on their map.

The most important thing is that we don't want sign out/offline users' location data on Firebase (because we want users only to be able to see online nearby users) so I use Firebase's `onDisconnectRemoveValue()` method to automatically remove disconnected users' data. The method worked great. BUT, if the app goes to the background (or screen is turned off), `onDisconnectRemoveValue` is fired too, so the data will be deleted (I don't want it to be deleted).

I searched the Internet, found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177034/ondisconnect-is-fired-if-app-goes-to-background-mode?rq=1).

This method is designed that way, I think I cannot do anything about it.

So my question is: If I want to remove a data on Firebase if the user is disconnected (loss internet connection OR app closed/killed), how can I do that?

---

Additional info: because I want users can updating their location to Firebase even if the App go to the background or device screen is off so I cannot check the connection at the client (can check, but when connection loss detected, cannot send remove data request to Firebase).

Comment: You can do this with an onDisconnect handler. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Comment: Thanks for comment, but as i said up there, by some magical ways the app lost connection with Firebase when i turn the screen off or press home button (go to background), so the onDisconnect fired which i dont want to

Comment: Sorry about that. It sounds like you have a very app specific definition of when a user is considered active or inactive, in which case Firebase likely has no a built-in primitive to help you detect it.